# Convert Costmap2D to OMPL State Space

Tags: ros, navigation, rrt, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a global planner plugin for the navigation stack using OMPL. I need to convert the Costmap2D in ROS to its corresponding State Space representation. Has anyone done this before?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246274/convert-costmap2d-to-ompl-state-space/) by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2016-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karuzel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29859/karuzel/) on 2017-03-29**:
Hey, have you solved your problem in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please refer to the following link to get an idea of how to access the states in OMPL and extract ROS-compatible information from it.

https://bitbucket.org/ompl/ompl/issues/282/how-to-access-the-values-of-states-in-the

---

Originally posted by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) with karma: 115 on 2017-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1